# Run a method once dom-repeat's rendering is all done

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, web-component

I have a dom-repeat element displaying records, and would like to run an operation once dom-repeat is *finished*. This is so that I can run:

```
    this.$.content.scrollTop = this.$.content.scrollHeight;
```

(It's a chat system, it would be silly not to scroll down to the last one).

It's a fairly normal dom-repeat template... I tried plugging myself as a filter for it, or observing the data, but in all cases I get called *before* rendering has happened.

Here is the dom-repeat -- how do I do this?

```
    <div class="content" id="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[!_dataThere(data)]]">
          <my-empty-list icon="question-answer" message="You haven't talk to this user yet. (You can do it now!)"></my-empty-list>
        </template>

        <hot-network manage-errors>
          <iron-ajax id="aj" auto url="{{_makeUrl(userId,userData.generic.id)}}" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>
          <template is="dom-if" if="[[_dataThere(data)]]">

            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">

              <div class$="message {{_theirsOrMine(item)}}">
                <div class="message-inner">
                  <div class="avatar"></div>
                  <div class="bubble">{{ item.message}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="meta">{{_formattedDate(item.added)}}</div>
              </div>

            </template>

          </template>
        </hot-network>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To register a one-time callback after the next render, use `Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, function() {...})`, where `this` is your Polymer object.

Example:

```
Polymer({
  _addItem: function() {
    this.push('items', new Item());
    Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => {
      // set scroll top
    });
  }
});
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rMEobp)

The method is currently undocumented in 1.x (even in its [source code](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/f770438/src/lib/render-status.html#L55)), but you'll notice it in the 2.0 upgrade guide in [*Callbacks contracts have changed*](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#callback-contracts-have-changed):

> Use the `Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender` function to register a one-time callback after the next render.

I first discovered it at Google I/O 2016 [*Practical lessons from a year of building web components*](https://youtu.be/zfQoleQEa4w?t=23m47s).

Comment: Geeee... where is this documented?!?!?

Comment: It's mostly undocumented :) but it effectively boils down to  `requestAnimationFrame()`.

Comment: Fantastic answer... somehow unrelated: what is *exactly* a render, in terms of polymer? Is it when ALL children in the light dom are ready()ed and rendered themselves? Or...?

Comment: Nudge? Maybe it would be nice to expand the answer a little explaining what Polymer means *exactly* by "a render"?

Comment: @Merc Based on the source, I believe a "render" simply means an animation frame. It has no relation to the render status of the element's children. The Polymer element's [`ready` callback](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#ready-method) implies the ready state of itself and its **registered local DOM children**. Note that it's possible for an element to have local DOM children that are not yet registered, but that does not block the element's own `ready` state.

Comment: @Merc Regarding *light DOM* children: `There are no guarantees about the initialization timing of light DOM children. In general elements are initialized in document order, so children are usually initialized after their parents.` For more info on initialization order and timing, the Polymer [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#initialization-order) can explain it much better than I can. I found it really helpful.